# Can't find Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-media-player

I got a work laptop that came loaded with Windows 7 Professional. I'm unable to find Windows Media Player on the machine.

C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player turns out to be empty.

I do understand that WMP should be included in Windows 7 Professional. Now, since Windows was installed from an image, is it possible that my IT department has decided not to include WMP (is that even possible?)

Any help in retrieving WMP is much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has it not just been removed from the Windows components?

In Control Panel, click Programs, then Turn Windows features on or off.

Under Media Features, Windows Media Player should be listed. Mark the checkbox and hit OK. You may need the Windows 7 install media available...

Answer (score 1):

From the [Windows Media Player page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-media-player) on Microsoft's site:

> *Included in most editions of Windows 7 (no download available).*
>
> For Windows 7 N or KN editions, download the [Media Feature Pack](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=178358).

So it looks like it was something that was removed by your IT department.

Comment: Isn't WMP 12 the current version?

Comment: @Jan - I misread which Windows version you were talking about. I've removed the incorrect answer and put up some (hopefully) useful information instead.

Comment: Thanks. That's about as much as I found out as well. Bummer. Looks like I'll have to use WMP 11 unless someone else has a good idea.

Comment: Depending on how locked down your system is you might be able to use the windows update website to upgrade to WMP12 after installing 11.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the only answer I found that actually worked. Everything else was outdated or didn't work for N versions.